# Limit row comparitive between querys

Tags: mysql, left-join

I am going to extend other question that I ask in SO because the questions is different. I have two table:

**article_en:**

```
ID  TITLE      CONTENT       HOME_POSITION
1   article1   blablablabla  1
2   article2   blablablabla  2
3   article3   blablablabla  3
4   article4   blablablabla  4
5   article5   blablablabla  5
6   article6   blablablabla  6
7   article7   blablablabla  7
```

**article_nl:**

```
ID  TITLE    CONTENT        ENGLISH_ID  HOME_POSITION
1   article1 blablablabla   5           1
2   article1 blablablabla   7           2
```

I execute this query to get the latest articles from article_en which are not already added as foreign key in article_nl.

```
SELECT *
FROM article_en
    LEFT JOIN article_nl
        ON article_en.id != article_nl.english_id
ORDER BY article_en.home_position;
```

This query works, but the problem is that I have more than 25.000 rows in each table, so query is really slow (more than 25 seconds), so I want to limit this query to compare last 100 articles between both tables. I mean, if there are in the last 100 english article some article which is not in added as foreign key in the last 100 netherlands article.

I tried with different strategy as:

```
SELECT *
FROM article_en
    LEFT JOIN article_nl
        ON article_en.id != article_nl.english_id
ORDER BY article_en.home_position DESC limit 100;
```

It helps, but its not working. Maybe I have to change my strategy and try with other kind of query and not using a Left join.

Comment: tried simply doing SELECT TOP 100?

Comment: Try using Sub-query where instead of join, you select id from other table and set it in where condition with IN query.

Comment: Thank you guys, you put me in the right direction. I realize that a left join is not my best choice and I change to a left outer join and right now the query is really fast. 

SELECT * FROM article_en
LEFT OUTER JOIN article_nl
ON article_en.id = article_nl.english_id
WHERE article_nl.id IS null ORDER BY home_position DESC limit 100

Comment: Left join *is* left outer join. They return what inner join returns plus unmatched left table rows extended by nulls. Do you want those rows?? I doubt it. Your comment's query uses a left join idiom to calculate ANTIJOIN extended by nulls, ie rows that didn't match in an inner join, extended by nulls, If you select only left table columns, that's EXCEPT/MINUS. Which you could write as left table WHERE subrow NOT IN  right table. Please read & act on [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

What you want (comparing the last 100 in both tables) is possible using subqueries.

An example:

```
SELECT TOP 100
* FROM
article_en
WHERE article_en.id NOT IN (SELECT english_id FROM article_nl)
ORDER BY home_position
```

This is still going to be somewhat slow, since you'll be comparing against all the english_id's in article_nl every time, but should be faster then what you're doing.

If you only want to check against the 100 latest articles in `article_nl`, you can do that by changing the subquery to `(SELECT TOP 100 english_id FROM article_nl)`, but be aware that this may cause false positives as it will only check if the id doesn't exist in the latest 100 records of `article_nl`

Answer (score 0):

What about something like...

```
SELECT *
FROM article_en
LEFT JOIN article_nl
ON article_en.id = article_nl.english_id
WHERE article_nl.english_id IS NULL
ORDER BY article_en.home_position;
```

Then you can TOP/LIMIT your 100 records as you prefer